# Create a class called CreditCard using the __init__ method to assign values for current_balance and available_credit

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Additional Problem Details:

- Initialize the current_balance at 0 and available_credit at 10,000.
- Complete a method called makePurchase that adds to the current balance and takes away from the available credit. This means an exception will need to be raised if there is an attempt to purchase more than what is available.
- Write a second method called makePayment that has amount as a parameter which reduces the current balance and adds to the available credit.

**My current code:**

```
class CreditCard:
    """ BankAccount class for representing an account within a bank. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ initialize the current_balance """ 
        self.current_balance = 0 #initialize current balance 
        self.available_credit = 10000 #initialize available credit 


    def getBalance(self):
        """ return the current_balance """
        return self.current_balance

    def getAvailableCredit(self):
        """ return the available_credit """
        return self.available_credit

    def makePurchase(self, amount):
        try:
            if (amount <= self.available_credit):
                return (self.available_credit - amount) #deduct from available credit
                return (amount + self.current_balance) #increment current balance
            else:
                raise Exception('Insufficient funds!')
        except Exception as error:
            print('Purchase Error: ' + str(error)+'\n')

    def makePayment(self, payment): #write a payment function 
        try:
            if (payment <= self.current_balance):
                return(payment + self.available_credit) #increases available_credit by amount
                return(self.current_balance - payment) #reduces current balance by amount
            else:
                raise Exception('Payment larger than outstanding balance!')
        except Exception as error:
            print('Payment Error: ' + str(error)+'\n')
```

The second part of the problem (not listed) asks to  perform the following transactions:

- Display the available credit
- Make a purchase of $1237
- Display the available balance
- Make a payment of $100
- Make a purchase of $11.50
- Display the available balance
- Display the available credit
- Make a purchase of $8,900.

Every time I make a transaction, it does it from the original balance instead of from the running balance. For instance, I used the following code when making a purchase of $8,900:

**In:** `print(cc.makePurchase(8900))`

**Out:** `1100 #should be getting an error instead due to over-drafting the account.`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that you are returning the new value instead of modifying the object property, so change the returns as follows,

```
self.available_credit = self.available_credit - amount
self.current_balance = self.current_balance + amount
```

In this way, you are modifying the value of the available_credit and the current balance.

Repeat this change for the other return statements